# Please help. I get this error after upgrade to 19.04

Tags: dpkg

I am fairly new to Ubuntu.  Our family computer's hard drive failed last winter so, with the new one, I wasn't flipping for Windows again because this just more or less checks mail, surfs the web and plays games.  SO, i have used ubuntu in the past and like it.  Anyway, long story short, I upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04 and had a couple of errors.  The computer runs fine, but I cannot install other software it seems.  Trying to get flash to work, so my wife can play scrabble.  I do not believe it is a hardware issue.  I've rebooted the computer several times without issue.  This is new after the upgrade to 19.04.  There were a couple of errors while the upgrade was running.  One was something about xscreensaver locked and needed unlocked or something.  I do not remember the rest.  It seems to function normally other than not being able to install anything further.  the following I get while trying to instal:

```
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.115+2.02+dfsg1-12ubuntu2) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Could not prepare Boot variable: Invalid argument
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed | grub-efi-arm64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Mike

Comment: First suggestion is `sudo apt -f install`  (ie. ask the system to attempt to fix (-f) prior issues).  The actual error may be above what you posted (the error status 1 is often a repeat for a message further up the report listing which has text instead of the return(1) state)

Comment: I get the same error after running -f install.  This is the full result of the -f insall  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.115+2.02+dfsg1-12ubuntu2) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Could not prepare Boot variable: Invalid argument
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error

Comment: Please add additional information to your question (edit it, and place it there.)  IO errors can be permissions, but usually are hardware failings (because of power glitch, to failing device) so I'd firstly check your hardware health (ie. SMART data of sdd/hdd..) using `smartctl`, `gnome-disks` etc.  I'd not be booting your system until you've proven your hardware isn't failing (ie. use install media as a 'live' system and use that instead).  Putting the message in your question with different formatting may change what I see; as IO error is glaring as presented.